# still getting angular not defined

Tags: angularjs

this is html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="myApp">

    <head>

        <title>BlogIt!</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="myCtrl">

        {{message}}

    </body>

</html>
```

this is js file

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){

    $scope.message = "Welcome to BlogIt!";

})
```

Comment: Do you check your console where it gives error

Comment: You delcare angular module as **myApp** but where's ng-app in html ? you've to first define there.

Comment: Are you sure `bower_components/angular/angular.min.js` is correct path?

Comment: SPnl is right u have to define first ng-app then ng-controller

Comment: show the folder structure.

Comment: app.js stopped> Process exited with code:1

Comment: index.html stopped> Process exited with code: 127

Comment: blogit>bower_components>app.js>index.html @SachilaRanawaka

Comment: yes its the right path @AvneshShakya

Comment: Can you try this `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">` insteadof `bower_components` url one? 

If still there then try path of `app.js`. you can try this `<script type="text/javascript" src="./app.js"></script>`

Answer (score 2):

Edit with this :

```
<head>
    <title>BlogIt!</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    {{message}}
</body>
```

Comment: still getting the same result

Comment: This html and your script is correct. check that angular js file you loded or try with angular cdn.